# What is the pmf of an exponential distribution?

Tags: probability

I've been able to find the PDF and CDF but I cannot find the pmf of an exponential distribution anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it doesn't have one. A probability mass function $p(x) = Pr(X=x)$ only makes sense for discrete random variables X. For continuous random variables, you integrate the density to get a probability; for discrete random variables, you sum the point masses to get the probability for an event.